# About a theorem in continuity of a function

Tags: limits, continuity

In the book I saw a theorem about a continuous function:
[image]

and it gives proof like this:
[image]

The thing I'm wondering is that it seems doesn't depend on the continuity of the function.

For example, if function $f$ is not continuous at point $a$ but have limit $L>0$. Then:
$0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

And then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ can be turned in to a inequality: $-\epsilon<f(x)-L<\epsilon$, and in particular,$\epsilon=\frac{L}{2}$

Then $0<\frac{L}{2}<f(x)$. Hence, this is also true that even though $f$ is not continuous at $a$ and only has the limit, the theorem still holds.

Thus, I'm wondering what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering what's wrong here.

Nothing, your proof is fine.

I guess the motivation for such theorem statement is that continuity is a very natural assumption and it illustrates the main idea very well, while the assumption with a positive limit feels more technical even though it is more general.